# Как получить адрес структуры по переменной из нее

Tags: c++, c

Имеется такая структура в скомпилированном приложении:

```
typedef struct
{
int timer;
float time[2];
byte jjjj;
} sturcture_t;
sturcture_t stackoverflow;
```

У меня есть адрес stackoverflow.time[0] в памяти.

Как найти всю структуру, чтобы хукнуть ее?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <stddef.h> // или <cstddef> для C++ 

float *time_0 = ...;   
...
structure_t *s = (structure_t *) ((char *) time_0 - offsetof(structure_t, time[0]));
```

В реализациях для Linux эта идиома доступна через макро `container_of`.

Что значит "хукнуть ее", однако, не ясно.

Comment: А почему нельзя просто сделать что-то в стиле `(sturcture_t *) (&time[0] - 1)`? Поля структуры расположены не последовательно?

Comment: @Артём Оконечников: А откуда взялось `- 1`?

Comment: 1 размер типа указателя, т.е. 4 байта

Comment: Т.е. в этом конкретном случае, в этой структуре перед массивом `float` расположена переменная `int`. Почему просто нельзя уехать на 4 байта влево от первого элемента массива, раз размер типов совпадает? Вопрос исключительно из праздного любопытства.

Comment: @Артём Оконечников: Если считать, что между полями нет паддинга, то да - это именно то, что нам нужно: уехать на 4 байта влево. Но зачем заниматься *угадыванием* размеров, если у нас есть стандартное макро `offsetof`, которое нам надежно, точно и портабельно скажет, на сколько байтов влево нам надо уехать? В данном случае `offsetof` и даст нам значение `4`.

Comment: (При чем здесь "размер типа указателя" и почему он должен быть "4 байта" мне не ясно.)

Comment: А чему он должен быть равен? В общем, мой вопрос заключался в следующем, почему нельзя просто сместиться влево на 4 байта `(int *)item.time - 1` ваш ответ «потому что паддинг» меня более чем устраивает.

Answer (score 0):

```
auto s = *(stackoverflow*)(&(stackoverflow.time[0]) - offsetof(stackoverflow, time[0]))
```

Comment: Вызов макро, на самом деле, надо записать так: *offsetof(sturcture_t, time )* Во всяком случае, на С.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/246504)

Comment: @АртёмОконечников в с++ можно так вычислить адрес, только... пожалуй ответ не совсем полный. То что нужно дополнить - соглашусь.